# Adding a dynamic MultiFrame index

Tags: python, pandas

a question which I'm not able to answer myself. I've created a dataframe containing tournament rankings. The dataframe is the result of a group action and looks like this:

```
d ={'games': {('A', 1, 'Hawks'): 6,
   ('A', 4, 'Eagles'): 6,
   ('B', 2, 'Sparrows'): 6,
   ('B', 3, 'Falcons'): 6,
   ('B', 5, 'Vultures'): 6},
   'points': {('A', 1, 'Hawks'): 12,
   ('A', 4, 'Eagles'): 9,
   ('B', 2, 'Sparrows'): 11,
   ('B', 3, 'Falcons'): 8,
   ('B', 5, 'Vultures'): 2}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).rename_axis(['group','team_id','team_name'])
print(df)
```

```
| group | team_id | team_name | games | points |
| ----- | ------- | --------- | ----- | ------ |
| A     |       1 | Hawks     |     6 |     12 |
|       |       4 | Eagles    |     6 |      9 |
| B     |       2 | Sparrows  |     6 |     11 |
|       |       3 | Falcons   |     6 |      8 |
|       |       5 | Vultures  |     6 |      2 |
```

And so on. Current grouping index is group/team_id/team_name. Now I'd like to insert an index at position 1 (after group) having the placement of the team, but dynamically to every group.

The result should look like this:

```
| group | rank | team_id | team_name | games | points |
| ----- | ---- | ------- | --------- | ----- | ------ |
| A     |    1 |       1 | Hawks     |     6 |     12 |
|       |    2 |       4 | Eagles    |     6 |      9 |
| B     |    1 |       2 | Sparrows  |     6 |     11 |
|       |    2 |       3 | Falcons   |     6 |      8 |
|       |    3 |       5 | Vultures  |     6 |      2 |
```

Since I do not have much experience on handling MultiIndexes in Pandas I need some advice on how to handle this.

Many thanks in advance!

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `rank` with `ascending=False` to get rank for each group and then set index with `append=True` , then [`reorder`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) the levels:

```
idx = df.groupby(level=0)['points'].rank(ascending=False).astype(int).rename('rank')
df = df.set_index(idx,append=True).reorder_levels([0,-1,1,2])
print(df)
```

---

```
                              games  points
group rank team_id team_name               
A     1    1       Hawks          6      12
      2    4       Eagles         6       9
B     1    2       Sparrows       6      11
      2    3       Falcons        6       8
      3    5       Vultures       6       2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not notice the function `rank`at all. Really useful!